# Levenshtein type algorithm with numeric vectors

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance

I have two vectors with numeric values. Such as

```
v1 <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
v2 <- c(54, 23, 12, 53, 7, 8)
```

I would like to compute the number of **insertions**, **deletions** and **replacements** that I need to turn one vector into the other with certain costs per operation **c1** **c2** and **c3** respectively. I am aware that the function *adist* on the base package does this for strings but I have no knowledge of the equivalent function with numbers.

I thought about referencing each number with a letter but I have more than 2000 unique numbers so if anybody knows how to get 2000 different characters in R that would also be a solution for me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 26^3 > 2000. Therefore try `combn(letters,3)`

Comment: not even. combn(c(letters, LETTERS), 2) would even be better. But that is not the point of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An integer vector can be seen as a single string encoded in UTF-32 (in which one Unicode code point is represented as a single 32-bit integer). You may obtain an "ordinary" string, just by converting such a vector to UTF-8 with `intToUtf8`.

```
intToUtf8(c(65, 97))
## [1] "Aa"
```

By the way, `adist` does `utf8ToInt` (reverse op) by default on its inputs anyway. So internally, it computes the results according to integer vectors. No big hack.

This is the solution.

```
adist(intToUtf8(c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)), intToUtf8(c(54, 23, 12, 53, 7, 8)), counts=TRUE)
##      [,1]
## [1,]    5
## attr(,"counts")
## , , ins
## 
##      [,1]
## [1,]    0
## 
## , , del
## 
##      [,1]
## [1,]    1
## 
## , , sub
## 
##      [,1]
## [1,]    4
## 
## attr(,"trafos")
##      [,1]     
## [1,] "SSSSDMM"
```

The above code should work if at least all the numbers are strictly greater than 0.
R treats Unicode code points quite liberally (in fact, too liberally, but in this case you're a winner), even the largest possible integer is accepted:

```
utf8ToInt(intToUtf8(c(2147483647)))
## 2147483647
```

If you have a vector with negative values, you may transform it somehow, e.g. with `x <- x-min(x)+1`.

If you need different costs for insertion, removal, replacement, check out the `adist's` `costs` argument. There is also a package called [stringdist](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/index.html), which included many other string metrics. The above scheme should also work there.