# Calculating the edit-distance between two lists of integers in R

Tags: r, edit-distance

I would like to use R to compare a lot of integer lists, using edit-distance.
Ex: `list1[231, 3883, 21099, 12, 2]` and `list2[433, 3883, 12, 919, 2]`

I'd like to get just the distance between those two list. Ex. with the lists above, the distance would equal `3`. Because to make `list2` like `list1`, you would `substitute 231` for `433`, then `add 21099` after `3883`, then `delete 919`.

I would like to find how many adds and removes I would need to make list1 look like list2. I know that R has the built in function: `adist()`. That however, only seems to work for comparing strings (not even lists of strings). Google keeps pushing me to `adist()` and `dist()` neither of which are going to solve this problem. I'd rather not reinvent the wheel, so is there a function already in existence? I've attempted to rewrite `adist()` as found here: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/13555814/
but its too complex for my current R ability.

Comment: `adist(list1,list2)` works fine if you make your data vectors, e.g: - `list1 <- c(231,3883,21099,12,2)` It converts numbers to strings automatically.

Comment: That seems to calculate the distance between each individual point and dump the result to a matrix. Ex `list1 <- c(101, 4333)` and `list2 <- (32, 101)` then `adist(list1, list2)` outputs: `row1: 3, 0` `row2: 3, 4` I'll add a better explanation of what I'm looking for above.

Comment: That's a more interesting question then - I'm not sure off the top of my head how that would work.

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674038/levenshtein-type-algorithm-with-numeric-vectors) is whaty ou were after?